# How to bulk migrate domains from GoDaddy to Namecheap without downtime?

Tags: dns, godaddy

I have about 5-10 domains registered by GoDaddy. The DNS on most of these is provided by GoDaddy as well.

I'm using [SOPA](http://venturebeat.com/2011/12/29/not-even-a-shift-to-full-sopa-opposition-can-stop-go-daddy-from-hemorrhaging-customers/) as an excuse to migrate away - I've hated GoDaddy for several years now, and Namecheap seem to be a popular alternative.

What's a good receipe for quickly migrating several domains with no/little downtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There shouldn't be any downtime when migrating domains between registrars. All you have to do is initiate the transfers from the destination registrar. Usually when you do this, it'll let you put in your desired nameservers or the new registrar will just use the current nameservers. This way, once the transfer goes through from the source registrar's end, the destination registrar will take over without any interruption in service.

Namecheap also has [this page](http://www.namecheap.com/domains/transfer-a-domain.aspx) which should allow you to do bulk transfers.

Note: You may need to obtain an EPP code from your current registrar and/or unlock the domain(s). [Here are Namecheap's directions for GoDaddy transfers](http://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/876/83/how-to-transfer-a-domain-from-godaddy).

Comment: But *changing NSes* (Ripper have to do it also) **can have** some side-effects

Answer (score 1):

If you'll move NSes for your domains, before transfer decrease TTL for domains (for all RR) to reasonable small value (some hours), wait for expiration of old (long TTL) records and transfer NSes only after it